# Python- Totaling items from a list, passing list to be written, read file and display numbers originally entered

Tags: python, arrays, string, sum

I've been working on this code for the past couple of days now. I'm having trouble with 2 things (maybe 3 if I'm not converting the list from a string to integers properly):

1)summing up the total of the numbers in the array. The total displays the last number entered in the this format ([9],9).

2)From the readData module, displaying the numbers that were originally entered. It returns the number of items, which is 5

**Example Output**

Please enter a number between 1- 10: 1

Please enter a number between 1- 10: 3

Please enter a number between 1- 10: 5

Please enter a number between 1- 10: 7

Please enter a number between 1- 10: 9

The total of the numbers you entered is: ([9], 9)

The data was written to the file.

The numbers you entered are:
5

The data has been read from the file. 
        ITEMS = 5

```
    def main():

        #assign variable to call a function
        numArray = inputNumbers()

        #assign variable to call a function and
        #pass the argument 'numArray'
        total = addNums(numArray)

        #display the total amount of the numbers in array combined
        print('The total of the numbers in the list is', total)

        #call function to write data to a file passing argument numArray
        writeArray(numArray)

        #call function to read data from a file
        readArray()

    def inputNumbers():

        #set empty array to append items to later
        numArray = [] 

        #set up try and except to ensure user puts in a number
        #and that the number is between 1 and 10
        try:

            #set up a for loop for the user to be able to enter up to 5 items
            for count in range(1, ITEMS + 1):
                print(count,')Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ', sep= '', end='')
                numbers = int(input())

                #set up while loop so that the user is able to reenter a number if they
                #enter a number outside of 1-10
                while numbers < 1 or numbers > 10:
                    print('An error occurred. Please make sure you enter' \
                          'only a number.')
                    print()
                    print(count,')Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ', sep= '', end='')

                    #convert numbers to an integer
                    numbers = int(input())

            #use append method to add the numbers entered to empty array  
                numArray.append(numbers)

            #return numArray back to the main function
            return numArray

        #declare except method in the event user enters anything that is not a numer
        except:
            print('An error occurred. Please ensure that you are entering the information properly.')

    #call function to get the total sum of the numbers in the array
    def addNums(numArray):

        total = 0
        #calculate the total sum of the numbers 

        for i in numArray:
            total += i

        #return total back to the main function
        return total

    #declare function to write the data from the array to a file
    def writeArray(numArray):

        #open the file
        num_file = open('Exam2.dat','w')

        #declare for loop to convert all the integers back to a string
        for index in numArray:
            num_file.write(str(index) + '\n')

        #close the file
        num_file.close()

        print('The data has been written to the file.')

    def readArray():

        #open read file
        num_file = open('Exam2.dat','r')

        numbers =  num_file.readline()
        numbers = numbers.rstrip('\n')
        #create a while loop to execute as long as the index is 1 less than the max amount of items
        #and also will stop the program from continually running once it hits EOF
        while numbers != ' ' :

            #display the numbers that were originally entered
            print('Here are the numbers that you entered:', numbers)

            #read each line of the file and strip the separate line after
            numbers = num_file.readline()
            numbers = numbers.rstrip('\n')


        #close file
        infile.close()
```

Comment: Is the output you get correct? If not, what output do you expect?

Comment: I changed the code by indenting the numArray.append(numbers) one more indent. I'm not having trouble with a continuous loop in readData(), where "Here are the numbers you entered: " continuously loops. I need to exit the program without crashing the program. Any advice here?

Comment: Where does your program crash?